# Deleting option from select component using jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a form where a user can input several instances of data on experiments. Each time an user enters an instance a row is created on a dynamic table.

It also adds an option to two select components that the user needs to use to fill in more data from the form. So for example a user fills in info from Experiment 1 and Experiment 2 so a table will be created with two rows one for Experiment 1 and one for Experiment 2 and the select components will have two options Experiment 1 and Experiment 2.

Each row of that table has a delete row cell that the user can click to delete that row. Deleting the row is working fine but I'm having trouble deleting the option from the select component. For that I'm doing this in jQuery

```
if($(obj).closest('table').attr('id')=='experiment-table'){
    var exp = tr.find('td:first').text();

    var txt = 'Experiment ' + exp;

    $('#exp-select option[value="'+exp+'"]').remove();
    $('#expind-select optgroup[text="'+txt+'"]').remove();
}
```

So what this code does, supposedly, is look for the id of the closest table tag to obj, obj in this case is the table row (tr) where the user clicked the delete button.
Then it finds the first cell of the tr and extracts the text since that is the number of the Experiment it has to delete from the select options. So if the user wants to delete Experiment 1 then var exp will be equal to 1 or 2 for Experiment 2.
Then var txt will have the text "Experiment 1" or "Experiment 2" depending on which experiment the user chose to delete.

I debugged this part and everything is working fine, I also checked the select components and they have the Experiment 1 and Experiment 2 options like they are supposed to have.

Then I try to remove the options from the select components using the last two lines of that code. I tried using the value of the option for the first component which in case of Experiment 1 is just 1 or 2 for Experiment 2 and the text of the option for the second component which for Experiment 1 is exactly Experiment 1 for example.

The thing is that these two last lines are not working. According to the debugger `#exp-select option[value="'+exp+'"]` has a length of 0 even though I can see the options on the component and one option is Experiment 1 with value 1 and the other is Experiment 2 with value 2. I also tried to use the text instead of the value but it didn't work and it also shows a length of 0.

Any ideas?

Edit: Adding dropdown code

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exp_select">Experiment:</label>
                    <select class="form-control select-fill" id="exp_select" title="">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

And this is how I add an option each time

```
var rowCount = $('#experiment-table tr').length;
$('#exp_select').append($('<option>', {
    value: rowCount,
    text: 'Experiment '+ rowCount
}));
```

Comment: Can you post the generated markup for the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[attr*=""]` attribute contains selector:

```
$('#exp-select option[value*="'+exp+'"]').remove();
$('#expind-select optgroup[text*="'+txt+'"]').remove();
```

---

or you can also use `.filter()` method:

```
$('#exp-select option').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr("value").indexOf(exp) != -1;
}).remove();
$('#expind-select optgroup').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr("text").indexOf(txt) != -1;
}).remove();
```

Comment: I tried both of these options and the result was the same. The option was not removed. I added the initial html code for the first dropdown and the jQuery code I use to create new options. That code works fine though.

Comment: Silly me, I just notice I was using exp-select as id and on the html it was exp_select. Now it works with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.remove()` for `option[value*=+VAL+]`

From select list find options which contains value of your choice and then remove from DOM

```
$('#exp-select option[value*="'+exp+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer. We are voting to delete this question because of its **length** and **content**.

Comment: The same as above, it doesn't make a difference if I add the * symbol.